# Angular http get does not work for localhost response status -1

Tags: angularjs, cors, same-origin-policy

I have a simple webservice:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="hello")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{firstName}/{lastName}",method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public String hello( @PathVariable("firstName") String firstName,
                     @PathVariable("lastName") String lastName) {

        return String.format("{\"message\":\"Hello %s %s\"}", firstName, lastName);

    }

}
```

which I running in port 8081 and I can get it from browser.

Howerver, from angular, I get error, response status -1:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

<p>Today's welcome message is:</p>

<h1>{{myWelcome}}</h1>

</div>


<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://localhost:8081/hello/test/gfgg")
  .then(function success(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = "response.data";
  }, 
  function error(response) {      // Response status code 4xx and 5xx
            console.log("error");
            $scope.myWelcome = response.status + ": " + JSON.stringify(response);
         });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I use some public service, like, http://md5.jsontest.com/?text=1234, the angular works fine.

Does any one know how to make local service works in angular?

Comment: Status of -1 usually happens with a CORS error. You should see the message in the developer console.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks  georgeawg. Yes, it is CORS error. When I open the developer console, I can see:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/v1/organizations/e254f8c-c442-4ebe-a82a-e2fc1d1ff78a/licenses/f3831f8c-c338-4ebe-a82a-e2fc1d1ff78a' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

To solve this, in my RestController, I added:
@CrossOrigin("*")

Then I can get the service result from angular client call.